# How can I apply a variable as an element ID with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I saw in the firebug the ID is like this whereas I want the value of `existingProductArray[i]` to be the ID. What am I doing wrong?

```
var html ='<li id="existingProductArray[i]">'
       + '<input type="image" id="existingProductArray[i]" src="images/subtract.png" onclick="javascript:deleteProduct(this.id)" href="#">'
       + existingProductArray[i]
       + '</li>';
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
 var id = existingProductArray[i];

 var html ='<li id="' + id + '">'
           + '<input type="image" id="' + id + '" src="images/subtract.png" onclick="javascript:deleteProduct(this.id)" href="#">'
           + id
           + '</li>';
```

## But

ID hence the name should be unique you are giving 2 elements the same ID ( that's a bad idea )

Answer (score 3):

Try changing:

`+ '<input type="image" id="existingProductArray[i]" src="...>'`

to

`+ '<input type="image" id="'+existingProductArray[i]+'" src="...>'`

So in your line of code it was just using it as text string. You need to break out of the string and do it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to close the quotes and concatenate it in with `+`:

```
var html ='<li id="existingProductArray[i]">'
               + '<input type="image" id="' + existingProductArray[i] + '" src="images/subtract.png" onclick="javascript:deleteProduct(this.id)" href="#">'
               + existingProductArray[i]
               + '</li>';
```

Answer (score 1):

**your reference is inside the quotations**

```
       var html ='<li id="'+existingProductArray[i]+'">'
               + '<input type="image" id="'+existingProductArray[i]+'" src="images/subtract.png" onclick="javascript:deleteProduct(this.id)" href="#">'
               + existingProductArray[i]
               + '</li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

So I also wanted to declare an div id with a before declared variable and it worked with:

```
<script>
   let index1 = 1;
   let index2 = 2;
</script>

<div id="prefix"+index1++index2+></div>
```

so in this case the "prefix" can be anything you want e.g. "Version" and it adds the variables (index1 and index2) to it so the result you'll get is Version12 as the id.

Comment: You can't combine JS variables in HTML like that, take a look at all the other answers that do the string manipulation in JS.