# How can I assign unique ID to innerhtml element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function:

```
function displayInputIntro() {
                var submitbutton = document.getElementById('submitbutton')
                var intro = document.getElementById('Intro') 
                var introNewSection = document.getElementById('intro-row')
                introNewSection.innerHTML += '<div class="col-lg-5 mb-lg-0 mb-4" id="intro">';
                submitbutton.style.display = ''
}
```

This function `displayInputIntro()` can be called multiple times, and it will insert this new section into the body of the HTML as many times as one decides to do so. Problem is, I want to add a unique identifier, so that if I were to add something like this:

```
introNewSection.innerHTML += '<div class="col-lg-5 mb-lg-0 mb-4" id="intro"><a href="javascript;;" onclick="deleteInputFunc()">Remove Input</a>';,
```

and click on `Remove Input`, then it would delete the input, not all of them.

I have tried something like this:

```
var uniqueID = new Date()
introNewSection.innerHTML += '<div class="col-lg-5 mb-lg-0 mb-4" id="' + uniqueID '"'><a href="javascript;;"  onclick="deleteInputFunc()">Remove Input</a>';, and click on `Remove Input`, then it would delete the input, not all of them.
```

but that doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: `.addEventListener()` + `this` + DOM traversal is a better solution.

Comment: _"I have tried something like this:"_ - that would still violate the basic rule that IDs must be unique, with the `id="intro"` part. _"How can I do this?"_ - the best way would be to do this _without_ IDs, IMHO. Pass `this` as parameter to the callback function (or even better yet, use `addEventListener` instead of inline attributes), and then navigate the DOM to the target element from there.

Comment: @CBroe you're right, sorry. I forgot to fix that in the question, i was typing it instead of copying.

Comment: @Andreas could you explain more what you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are passing an string to html code, not the real JS variable.
You can try something like this thant I found in [How can I apply a variable as an element ID with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6940497/1264804):

```
 var id = new Date();

 var html ='<li id="' + id + '">'
           + '<input type="image" id="' + id + '" src="images/subtract.png" onclick="javascript:deleteProduct(this.id)" href="#">'
           + id
       + '</li>';
```

Comment: Also, duplicates should be flagged as such. Don't re-post answers.

Comment: You should explain that in your answer.